# Enclose a last numeric value in a string in parentheses

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have text file which have word instances like `POP9`, `POP10` - in general `POPnumber`. The same file also has word instances such as `POP(1)`, `POP(2)`, i.e `POP(number)``.

I am looking for a method to convert all instances of `POPnumber` to `POP(number)` and let existing `POP(number)` instances unchanged. Any way I can achieve it via `sed`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sed 's/\(POP\)\([0123456789]\{1,\}\)/\1(\2)/g' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Where `\(...\)` are used to *capture* what's matched so they can be used in the replacement in `\1`, `\2`, `[0123456789]` matches any single character in the set, and `\{1,\}` matches one or more of the previous thing, here digits.

If your `sed` supports `-E` for *extended* regular expressions, you can shorten it (and make it easier to read) with:

```
sed -E 's/(POP)([0123456789]+)/\1(\2)/g' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: What is the reason behind not using `[0-9]`? Are there locales around where this is different from `[0123456789]`?

Comment: @Philippos, yes, `[0-9]` often matches hundreds of characters that happen to sort between 0 and 9, if you want only `0123456789`, `[0123456789]` is your safest best, not even `[[:digit:]]` is guaranteed to match only those. You'll find several Q&As here covering that.

Comment: I tried the above solution, echo POP9 | sed 's/\(POP\)\([0123456789]\{1,\}\)/\1(\2)/g'
gives POP9 instead of POP(9). anything I missed?

Comment: Yes, you missed to escape the capturing parentheses on the lhs of the s/// command. Look closely at the first sed solution.

Comment: @user3060800 You missed the `-E` for extended regular expressions that you are using

Comment: Then he needs to remove the escapes on the braces.

Comment: Thanks :-). My bad. Works Fine.